# elementary 6.0 (Odin) daily (20210312) cannot be installed on VirtualBox (disk disabled)

Tags: system-installation

Just a quick question, if you can help here.

I am trying to install elementary OS 6.0 (daily build `20210312`) in a VirtualBox (ver. 6.1) running on a Xubuntu 20.10 (if that matters).

Playing with the "live" version is fine, but when I want to install it, it seems that the disk is not selectable.

[image]

Any ideas / hints, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the fact that the disk was too small.
Probably something like 15 GB would work. I made it 20 GB and so the disk could be selected and installation continue.

Filled in [this issue](https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/501) for tracking and solving it.